# How to not allow empty string to pass the RegularExpression condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

The documentation says that for the  [RegularExpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute?view=net-5.0) data annotation class, a null or empty string ("") value will automatically pass the check, and I should use a Required Attribute. My problem is that if I use a required Attribute, then when I initialize the profile data of an user with null values, the Required condition will fire and I don't want it to do that for the null values, only for the empty string ("").

How can I do this? Is there a way to separate the null and empty string conditions and not use Required, that checks both of them?

Comment: How about [MinLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.minlengthattribute?view=net-5.0)